# How to display code in a frame with ASCII ' and ` and evaluation of macros

Tags: macros, verbatim, fancyvrb

I want to display a block of code with ' and ` displaying as themselves and with evaluation of macros.The closest that I've been able to come was

```
\documentclass[b4paper]{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{upquote}
\begin{document}
Using alltt and upquote
\begin{alltt}
foo='Ren\'{e}'
bar=`Ren\'{e}`
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[b4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{upquote}

\begin{document}

Using upquote and fancyvrb
\begin{verbatim}
foo='Ren\'{e}'
bar=`Ren\'{e}`
\end{verbatim}
```

These correctly handle the **'**, **`** and **\**, but the text is not indented nor in a frame.

I tried using upquote and fancyvrb with frame=single

```
\begin{verbatim}[frame=single]
foo='Ren\'{e}'
bar=`Ren\'{e}`
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

These correctly handle the **'**, **`** and **\**, but the text is not indented nor in a frame.

The placement of the optional parameter matches the fancyvrb documentation; [frame=single] is treated as the first text line in the environment. Putting the parameters in the other order gives me

```
! Missing $ inserted 
<inserted text> 
$ 
l.16
```

The error line seems to be \end{verbatim}

The documentation for listings says that it is possible to escape LaTeX, but I have not been able to get that to work.

I tried putting everything in a framed environment, but that interfered with alltt and fancyvrb.

I have to edit the document on a platform that only supports two code pages per boot, and I need 437 and 850 there.

So what is my best way forward?

Comment: You need `Verbatim`, not `verbatim`, to use fancyvrb options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
\documentclass[b4paper]{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{upquote}
\begin{document}

Using alltt

\begin{alltt}
foo='Ren\'{e}'
bar=`Ren\'{e}`
\end{alltt}

Using framed alltt

\begin{framed}
\begin{alltt}
foo='Ren\'{e}'
bar=`Ren\'{e}`
\end{alltt}
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

I wanted to use fancyvrb, which lets me control the width, but it doesn't render properly. I'll use the stopgap above until I  figure out how to escape to LaTeX in listings,

Comment: You can accept own answer.